# How to Traverse a Lava Ocean?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I have created a world in a 1.8 snapshot version of minecraft because i wanted to play around with the custom world gen, i turned on lava oceans and it makes the world really cool.

I have tried using Boats - not working

Making a cobble bridge is slow, tedious and dangerous, are there any alternatives.

but how can i possibly traverse these?

Comment: Do you still have access to water?

Comment: Not currently, water lake and oceans are set to quite rare @Studoku

Comment: If getting across the overworld is your only concern, there's always the tried-and-true way of using Nether Portals.

Comment: A cobblestone bridge isn't dangerous--use sneak mode.  You can't fall off.

Comment: @LorenPechtel Unfortunately like many people i occasionally find that for no reason sneak stops working so its not safe for me, and it takes a very long time

Comment: @LorenPechtel it's safe as long as no mob comes to say hello :)

Comment: @Flaunting That's never happened to me.  Position yourself correctly and you can just sit there clicking every time you've moved far enough.

Comment: @Quentin Lava light keeps the mobs away, doesn't it??  (I've never tried bridging a lava sea.)

Comment: If you're close enough to it, yes. But until you're far enough from land, they can still spawn there and come for you (especially zombies, they have a huge search radius)

Answer (score 20):

For ease, safety and awesomeness of travel, I'd choose a redstone [Flying Machine](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Tutorials/Flying_technologies).

**Edit**: and here is a design I made a few days ago.

**The machine :**
[image]

It is symmetric, and its direction is determined by the position of the outer redstone blocks. On this picture it will go to the left.

**The dock :**
[image]

Pay attention to its orientation. The sticky piston on the bottom left should be on the side of the machine where the slime blocks protrude (i.e upwards in the picture of the machine). The obsidian block (or any non-pushable block) should line up with the pistons of the machine.

Note that the seemingly useless redstone line at the top of the picture is crucial. It provides the block update that kickstarts the engine.

**Detailed view of the dock :**
[image]

It doesn't need to be that fancy. Its task is to swap the positions of the outer redstone blocks when the machine arrives. Build two of these aligned right, and the machine will be able to go one way or the other with a single button click. You heard me right, fully automatic !

**Bonus !**
Put a minecart chest on one of the boats (place a block above, a rail on the block, a minecart on the rail and break the block). It will follow along !

All pistons with lime wool directly above or below are sticky, all the others are normal.

This contraption works as of 14w34b, and worked on several versions before (I don't know when the fall-through bug was fixed). It does not work on 14w30c, though.

I apologize for the jpg pictures. No idea why Pinta output that.

Comment: I've never used one of these before, but I know sometimes Minecraft doesn't handle the player being moved by blocks too well and you can glitch out of the mechanism pretty easily.  Does that happen very often with this type of machine?  If so, it may not be the safe method OP was asking for.  Otherwise, I love this answer.  Awesome and creative.

Comment: Also a link only answer for site purposes can you summarise and put an example in the question

Comment: I'd have never thought of that!  It's something else you might want to include in the answer, though.  If somebody comes here looking for an answer to the same question, they shouldn't have to dig through the comments to find out how to make the solution work.

Comment: great if you can post a design which is safe i will test it this evening

Comment: @Quentin can you also state that this only applies to 1.8 onwards as someone looking to traverse lava in the nether pre 1.8 won't be able to use this

Comment: @Flaunting theeere you go ! If you are not on the latest snapshot, make a test in creative mode so you don't burn to death if you're on a version where the fall-through bug is still present :)

Comment: @Quentin how do you stop it>?

Comment: Hop off and place an unmoveable block in front of it.

Comment: This is the coolest thing I have ever seen.

Answer (score 0):

Try water. If you have access to a water bucket, placing the water down will create a bridge of obsidian. Make sure, though, that you place the water near the lava, on land, and not on the lava. This method is 100% reusable if you can find any water.

Answer (score 0):

Use a piston bridge builder. Place a lever next to a piston facing the lava, put a block on, flick the lever, place another block, etc. It should look as shown.

L P B B B B B B

L = lever
P = piston
B = block

When the piston reaches its limit, build another one on top of the existing bridge.

Answer (score -3):

use Gravel.  You can drop those and they will sink to the bottom

Comment: Wouldn't this be much slower than just a cobble bridge? What advantage is there to using gravel?